# Aggregate function in Tuple Relational Calculus

Tags: sql, database

How do you translate a `COUNT` or a `GROUP BY` or any other aggregate function you find in SQL into TRC, i can't find any way on internet.

So I have a table `User`

```
    +----+----------+--+
    |    |   User   |  |
    +----+----------+--+
    | pk | email    |  |
    |    | password |  |
    |    | ...      |  |
    +----+----------+--+
```

And a table `frienship`

```
+----+-------------+--+
|    | FriendShip  |  |
+----+-------------+--+
| pk | user1_email |  |
| pk | user2_email |  |
|    | date        |  |
|    | accepted    |  |
+----+-------------+--+
```

And the following query in SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN friendship f ON (f.user1_email = u.email 
                                 OR f.user2_email = u.email)
GROUP BY u.email 
HAVING COUNT(u.email) < 3
```

I would like to transform this query into tuple relational Calculus, the `JOIN` and the `SELECT` are pretty straightforward, but for the `GROUP BY` and the `COUNT` I don't know.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Lennart says, it's not possible to express those functions so, I decided to transform the count in another way.

First let's assert the following predicate:

[image: Friends Predicate]

Then we can say that having 2 or less friends, is having 0 friends, 1, or 2. To have 1 friend is like saying that there exists a friend (friend1) for wich Friends(me, friend1) is true.

To have 2 friends, you must have 1 friend and another, different. And finally you must not have any more friend.

All this can be express like this:

[image: Querry]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can express aggregate functions in neither TRC nor RA. However, there have been proposals to extend them, see for example:

http://cis.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-612/NestedRelations/Extending%20Relational%20Algebra%20and%20Relational%20Calculus%20with%20Se.pdf

Comment: This link is not working.

Comment: @ForhadHossain, try using the wayback machine:
https://web.archive.org/web/20100606072450/http://cis.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-612/NestedRelations/Extending%20Relational%20Algebra%20and%20Relational%20Calculus%20with%20Se.pdf